# How do I install PDO in PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, pdo

I've read through the [PDO installation documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) in php.net.

But I don't understand what it's talking about, would anyone be so kind to explain to me the installation part in human language?

Comment: Is it not already included? [*PDO ships with PHP 5.1*](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php).

Comment: What environment are you trying to install on?  Ubuntu, Windows, OSX etc etc..

Comment: Starting with the generic PDO docs might help: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.installation.php, if not tell us your os/distribution and how you installed php.

Comment: I've installed xampp, and the php 5.3 is included in it. But when I connect to the database using pdo with wrong username, password, etc.., it won't display any error

Comment: Questions asking for configuration must include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. At present there's no clearly defined problem, and thus the question does does not have high value for future readers.

Comment: Why use a php version that was released 10 years ago?

Answer (score 0):

What [phpinfo(](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php)) says? Does it shows PDO section? 
As far as the errors, check your [error_reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [display_errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) settings. I guess you don't see any errors because of these settinigs.

Comment: Looks like I only don't get errors when the username I input is wrong, but wrong dbname and password will give me errors lol, any idea why this happens? :p

Comment: @siaooo, will you answer the damn questions instead of saying "I get no errors LOL ktxhbye" ?

Comment: @greg0ire: this question is pretty old now `;)`. I've voted to close, anyway.

Answer (score -5):

The Simplest Way is to install Xampp or Lamp and you have the most php modules installed with it!

Comment: I've installed xampp, and the php 5.3 is included in it. But when I connect to the database using pdo with wrong username, password, etc.., it won't display any error

Comment: Have you set your PHP or PDO to display error while Development ?? http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/1718 and http://php.net/manual/de/pdo.errorinfo.php for example!! or just look to Andrey Denisov comment!!

Comment: Here a really good Tutorials about PDO! i use it too sometimes! http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial.
Looks like I only don't get errors when the username I input is wrong, but wrong dbname and password will give me errors lol, any idea why this happens? :p